# Need to find the number of employee who are not in all department

Tags: mysql, group-by

i have a table T1 which has two columns `empname` , `department`

every emp must be in 37 department , but there are some employee who are in less than 37 department .

I need to find the names of emp who are not in all 37 departments.

i'm using a query :

`select empname from T1 having count (department) < 37;`

but it is not giving me the desired output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you are e.g. counting or summing the entire contents of a table, aggregate functions will require a `group by` statement. For example, if you are aggregating by counting the number of departments *by* employee, you must tell it to *group* by employee

```
select empname, count(*)
from t1
group by empname
having count(*) < 37
```

Comment: great Roka , thanks alot for this.
it means i have to add group by clause for this...

Comment: why the result is not coming without group by claus

Comment: Unless you are for e.g. counting or summing the entire contents of a table, aggregate functions will require a 'group by' statement.  For example, if you are aggregating by counting the number of departments BY employee, you must tell it to GROUP by employee.

Comment: More here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: one more thing , i have one more table T2 in which department column is also there..now i want to insert only those department in T1.department for those  employees whose names are not in all 37 department

Comment: Can you please raise that as a separate question on here?  If you are happy with the answer above, please click the "Accept" tick-mark. I'll keep an eye out for the new question.

Comment: It would be *really* great if you incorporated the explanation of why the `GROUP BY` was important into your answer.

Comment: @AndriyM - Sure, updated :-)