# Inserting filtered data from one table to another

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I need to find the number of `employees` who are not in all departments.

I have one more table `T2` in which same department column is present. Now I want to insert only those values of `department` which are not in `T1.Department` for those employees whose name doesn't appear in all 37 departments.

I'm using MySQL.

Do I need to make any procedure for this?

Reference to : [Need to find the number of employee who are not in all department](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46145/need-to-find-the-number-of-employee-who-are-not-in-all-department)

**Tables**

```
create table T1 (empname, department)
create table T2 (department)
```

Comment: Post your table definitions. One query like `insert into ... select .... where ....` should do the job; no need for procedure.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert the result of a SELECT using [INSERT ... SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html) syntax. To get rows from one table that do not have corresponding rows in another you can use the [A not in B](http://hashmysql.org/wiki/Select_rows_in_table_A_that_are_not_in_table_B) LEFT JOIN MySQL idiom or a similar one with [NOT EXIST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354002/mysql-select-where-not-in-table) subquery (though the latter is less efficient).

Please give your table details for more specific query.

Comment: Some more info here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46145/need-to-find-the-number-of-employee-who-are-not-in-all-department

Comment: so i need to use JOINS for this as well..??